# why XML is part of the web service standard but not JSON

Tags: xml, json, web-services

While reading books or blogs about web services, I see all will take XML as the standard message format.
As far as I know, we can also define message as JSON format in web services.
So why JSON is not taken as one of the standards in Web Service technologies?

Comment: "While reading books or blogs about web services, all will take XML as the standard message format" — Are you only reading blogs and books written before the JSON specification was published?

Comment: oh, I haven't realized it, the books I read are mainly published At the beginning of twenty-first Century, I didn't pay attention to the historical process for these technologies.

Comment: JSON didn't begin to hit people's radars until [around 2005](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=json#q=json&cmpt=q).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because at the time the various Web Service Standards<sup>1</sup> were written JSON was not established as a data format.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> "The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from".

<sup>2</sup> JavaScript object and array literals existed, but their use outside JavaScript code was yet to be identified.